# Distributed transactions accross Azure SQL and on premises sql server causes errors

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, transactionscope, msdtc

Is it possible to have a transaction between an on premises SQL Server instance and an Azure SQL database.

I have the following tests cases.

```
public class TransactionsTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var premisesDatabaseContext = new OnPremisesDatabaseContext();
        var azureSQLDatabaseContext = new AzureSQLDatabaseContext();

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            premisesDatabaseContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            azureSQLDatabaseContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var premisesDatabaseContext = new OnPremisesDatabaseContext();
        var azureSQLDatabaseContext = new AzureSQLDatabaseContext();

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            azureSQLDatabaseContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            premisesDatabaseContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems pretty straightforward. But both tests cases fails with different errors when I open the second connection.

Here is the errors details.

```
// TEST 1
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
--->
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       at System.Transactions.Transaction.GetPromotedToken()

// TEST 2
System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException:
There is a promotable enlistment for the transaction which has a PromoterType value that is not recognized by System.Transactions. 
1c742caf-6680-40ea-9c26-6b6846079764
```

I want to know if it is possible to accomplish this. If it's not possible, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You can't

Azure sql databases uses [Elastic Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview). While on premises servers uses `Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)`.

MSDTC is not supported on azure, and according to the elastic transactions documentation,

> Only transactions across databases in SQL DB are supported. Other X/Open XA resource providers and databases outside of SQL DB cannot participate in elastic database transactions. **That means that elastic database transactions cannot stretch across on premises SQL Server and Azure SQL Database**. For distributed transactions on premises, continue to use MSDTC.

- On premises SQL Server uses MSDTC, which is not available on Azure
  SQL Database.
- Azure SQL Database uses elastic transactions, which won't work with
  on premises SQL server.

The easiest solution would be to move all database to either Azure or on premises.