# SQL Server 2019 Express : reading from / writing to SQL Server database (serverless) - working in SSMS but failing when in an INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, linked-server

I've been struggling with a trigger on my SQL Server Express database that verifies an incoming record and then writes it to my Azure SQL database (serverless).

Initially I ran the "trigger t-sql" code as a standard query in SSMS (19.0 Preview 2); it worked, and transferred 50k of records into the Azure SQL database.

I then updated this T-SQL code to reference the [inserted] table, and manually inserted a row - and irrespective of what I did in terms of using / not using cursors, variables, `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION`, different users, and more the trigger failed to insert while the identical process run as a query from SSMS worked.

I then simplified the INSERT trigger to a simple:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tc_table_ITrig]
ON [dbo].[tc_table]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [SQL_Database].[DatabaseName].[schema].[Table]([Var1], [Var2], [Var3], [Var4])
        SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4
END;
GO
```

If I run the statement in SSMS it succeeds

If I insert into `[dbo].[tc_table]` (which initiates the trigger) the insert fails with the following message:

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "SQL_Database" returned message "The parameter is incorrect.".
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tc_positions_ITrig, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "SQL_Database" reported an error. One or more arguments were reported invalid by the provider.
>
> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure tc_table_ITrig, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "SQL_Database" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

I sincerely hope someone can give me guidance on this; I've been struggling with it for over a month.

Comment: Your title and tags conflict here. You've tagged [[tag:azure-sql-database]], which is a cloud service, but your title says SQl Server Express 2019; which is it?

Comment: Both. I have a public-facing Azure VM (Windows Datacentre 2022) on which I have installed SQL Express 2019. I have an Azure SQL Database (Serverless) on the same private network but that is inaccessible from the public net. Data arrives via TCP/IP Socket and injects into SQL Express. There I perform data (and originating IP) verification, clean up the data, and write processed data to SQL Database. A separate Azure VM running SQL Standard reads from SQL Database and makes the data accessible via https web.

Comment: I don't think Azure supports distributed transactions, so I don't think this would work. But is there any error in the Windows Application log,  Event Source: MSDTC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distributed transactions accross Azure SQL and on premises sql server causes errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320342/distributed-transactions-accross-azure-sql-and-on-premises-sql-server-causes-err)

Comment: The link from SMor is very useful because it confirms that what I am attempting to do is not catered for.

I add that although I have succeeded in Reading / Writing from a SQL Job; this is not possible in a trigger. By trial and error I've seen creating the linked server with Provider MSOLEDB-19 allows Writing from SQL-Express to SQL-Database (but fails on reading from SQL Database) using t-SQL. Creating the Linked Server using Provider SQL Native Client allows both Write and Read. I've not worked out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distributed transactions in SQL Server (Express) relies on MSDTC which does not exist for cloud services as Azure SQL Database. You cannot include an insert in your local db and in cloud db in the same transaction. Perhaps you are better off with building a solution based on [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Thank you, although I have considered, and will not go the Change Tracking route, this reply pointed out the fundamental problem I was overlooking; a Trigger is an implicit transaction and however I tried SL does not allow a Distributed Transaction to reside within a Local Transaction (I am sure someone has written about this and why it is not allowed; I simply accept it as a limitation). So I will revert to my original methodology which is - create a recurring loop with a delay, and within this loop read new data and write it to the SQL Database Serverless. I hoped for something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

To run distributed transaction, you need to make the settings in both machines.

[configure msdtc on sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/configure-msdtc-on-sql-server-and-adapter-client)

Comment: I have configured MSDTC using, amongst other referenced the following link [link](https://eugenechiang.com/2022/03/29/the-operation-could-not-be-performed-because-ole-db-provider-sqlncli11-for-linked-server-was-unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction/). The same functionality is not available on the receiving DB (SQL Database - Serverless). Meaning I was trying to process as if there were 2 machines (which I do on other solutions) but the problem for me is I am attempting to use an Azure Serverless DB to replace a physical VM - SQL instance.

Comment: MSDTC requires two systems to be on the same network and communicate with each other using network services to run correctly. I have not used Azure Serverless services. Maybe this link will help you. [azuresql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-transactions-overview?view=azuresql)